# Update SHA256 hashing into SQL Server Database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to hash the user password in SQL Server from C#, I followed the instruction as found in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608860/Understanding-and-Implementing-Password-Hashing link and I created the user table with three columns

```
UserID NVarchar(250)
UserPassword NVarchar(MAX)
UserSalt NVarchar(50).
```

It works fine when I insert user and can log in correctly, but when I update the `UserPassword` and `UserSalt`, then I can not log in with the updated user, saying the `UserPassword` and `UserSalt` are incorrect.

Any advise to follow?

Comment: You can hash a password with sql, you don't need to do it in c#.  Generally what I do is make my user table etc, then I write a stored procedure called "ValidateUser" that accepts UserName and PLain Text Password.  Then the stored procedure hashes the password and compares it against the hash in the database.

Refer to this documentation for how to hash in sql server.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: Personally I would not do this in the database, but rather in the server tier (ie not client-side). Also the link @Ryios gave you only hashes in a single pass (work factor=1)... doesn't use a salt so leaves you open to rainbow attacks...

Comment: You'll gain better insights from this [excellent link on hashing-security](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). It has examples for C#. But make sure you don't do this client-side! If you don't have a C# server tier then your option is doing this in SQL Server, but it will be cumbersome.

Comment: You can easily add salt before you send it to HASHBYTES...

Comment: Thanks @TT. it worked!